# Keep old form style in Redux Form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

For my react project I'm using reactstrap to style my form, but I want to turn it into a redux-form. Is there a way to keep the styling and still have it work without turning the inputs into a

Heres my current code:

```
<FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input label="sitName" component={renderField} type="text" name="siteName" id="siteName" placeholder={placeholders.siteName}/>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input className="form-control" type="select" id="counties">
                            <option className="selectDefault" disabled value={placeholders.siteCounties} selected>{placeholders.siteCounty}</option>
                            { counties.map(c => (<option key={c.value} value={c.value}>{c.display}</option>))}
                        </Input>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <Input type="textarea"  name="siteAddress" placeholder={placeholders.siteAdd} id="siteAddress" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="email" name="siteEmail" id="siteEmail" placeholder={placeholders.email} />
                    </Col> 
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="tel" name="siteNumber"  id="siteNumber" placeholder={placeholders.number}/>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
```

And for it to work it must be like so:

```
<Field
        name="siteName"
        type="text"
        component={renderField}
        label="Site Name"
      />
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @JackBashford Added

Comment: you can create a <InputContainer>, based on reactstrap input, but only with the div classes, and then, use normal <input> inner